# VS 2022 Form doesn't show up as in Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Within VS2022, when designing a form with a statusstrip, it looks like this:
[image: Form in designer]

But when compiled and run, it looks like this:
[image: Form as compiled]

I've cleaned, rebuild etc. but nothing helped.
Is this a VS2022 problem?
My other forms, with statustrip included, don't show this behavior.

Comment: Is the form simply shorter at runtime or do the controls wander down with it while staying behind the statusbar if you make it taller?

Comment: Form shows up as in the picture and is static. Even when I make the canvas much, much larger, it still comes up as shown.

Comment: Are you sure you don't set a `MaximumSize` or the `(Client)Size` in code somewhere?

Comment: Nope, it is a clean new Form with default settings. Just as the other (main) one.Even when I set the maximum size to e.g. 2000,4000 it still comes up wrong.

Comment: And there's no weird AutoSize set either? I think more code of the form and it's layout is needed to check on this.

Comment: Yes!, Thank you.
AutoSize was on and changing it to false solved it.
Still peculiar that the main form, which also has autosize on and a statusbar doesn't have this problem.
Anyway, solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from [Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777985/ray) solved it.

Comment: You may want to include that it was AutoSize being on.